# Does this integral $\int f_{X|Y}(x|y) dy$ has any meaning in probability or statistics

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose I have two random variables $(X,Y)$ with joint probability density given by $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$.  Does integral  \begin{align*}
\int  f_{X|Y}(x|y)   dy
\end{align*}

evaluate to something or has any meaning in any probability of statistics?

Comment: I doubt that this integral has any meaning, since let's say it is representation dependent. That is, density is just one of possible representations of measures (e.g. besides the measure itself you can represent it by CDF), but this integral does not convert back to a natural (conditional) measure since you are missing the $f(y)$ term.

Answer (score 1):

If you multiplied the integrand by $f_Y(y)$ then you would get the overall probability/density $f_X(x)$. However without that I'm not sure if there's any interesting meaning to the integral. If you integrate with respect to $y$ without taking the distribution of $y$ into account then in some sense you could probably get anything.

Comment: Thank I new the first part. Do you think it can be re-written some how? For example using base rule.

Answer (score 1):

In Bayesian inference, you've calculated the posterior distribution of $X$ using a uniform prior, which may or may not lead to a proper posterior distribution...

Comment: But here the integration is from $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Comment: @Boby, I know...the uniform prior is an improper prior, its not a true prior distribution but its used quite a bit in Bayesian inference when you don't want to emphasize any particular point *a priori*. Sometimes this causes the resulting posterior to be improper as well, sometime not. Anyway, that was the first thing that came to my mind when I saw the form of the integral.